# how to prevent inserting empty data into the table row using trigger in pl-sql

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g, sqlplus, plsqldeveloper

I'm trying to create a **before insert Trigger** in PL/SQL which will prevent inserting empty data into the table row. (A trigger to enforce not null condition and prevents inserting numbers or special characters.

This is the table I created.

```
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER 
(
  CUSTOMER_ID INTEGER 
, CUST_FORENAME VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL 
, CUST_SURNAME VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL 
, GENDER CHAR(1) 
, EMAIL_ADDRESS VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL 
, CONSTRAINT CUSTOMER_PK PRIMARY KEY (CUSTOMER_ID)
  ENABLE 
);
```

And the Trigger that I created.

```
create or replace
TRIGGER CUS_MAND before insert OR update on CUSTOMER
begin
  CASE
    WHEN :NEW.CUST_FORENAME = NULL
      THEN DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Please enter customer forename.');
    WHEN :NEW.CUST_SURNAME = NULL
      THEN DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Please enter customer surname.');
    WHEN :NEW.EMAIL_ADDRESS = NULL
      THEN DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Please enter customer email address.');
  END CASE;
END;
```

But this trigger is not working successfully. Can someone solve the problem for me please?

Comment: This the wriong use for a trigger.  Rely on the NOT NULL constraints to enforce the NOT NULL-ness and use client-side validation as well if you want.

Comment: Also, your question should describe in what manner "this trigger is not working successfully".

Comment: Client side validation means to check on the client part of the application if all the required fields are completed before sending information to the database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @APC pointed out, it would make more sense to use NOT NULL constraints than a trigger for this purpose.

However, if you want to use a trigger, you should raise an error instead of just printing to DBMS_OUTPUT because

- printing a message will not prevent insertion of the wrong data
- usually, INSERTS / UPDATES will be run by some kind of client program, and DBMS_OUTPUT will not be shown in this client program

Apart from that, you've got a couple of errors in your trigger:

- you need to declare your trigger as FOR EACH ROW, otherwise, you won't be able to use :NEW and :OLD (because your trigger will be fired once per *statement*, not once per *row*)
- your CASE statement lacks the DEFAULT branch, so if all checks are successfull, you'll get an error during execution; I'd use an IF instead

One possible solution:

```
create or replace trigger CUS_MAND before insert OR update on CUSTOMER
for each row        
begin
  if :NEW.CUST_FORENAME is NULL THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001,
                            'Please enter customer forename.');
  end if;
  if :NEW.CUST_SURNAME is NULL THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20002,
                            'Please enter customer surname.');
  end if;
  if :NEW.EMAIL_ADDRESS is NULL THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20003,
                            'Please enter customer email address.');
  END if;
END;
```

Here, I use RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR to raise a user-defined exception; you can either use the same error number (-20001) for all errors or use the number to distinguish between them.

Answer (score 0):

You are checking for null values the wrong way:

```
:NEW.CUST_FORENAME = NULL
```

Null values checking must use "is null" or "is not null". Equal operator doesn't work. Nothing is ever equal or different to NULL.

So, if A := null:

```
a = Null => false
a != null => false
a is null => true
a is not null => false
```

Also, your trigger should be "FOR EACH ROW" as pointed by Frank Schmitt.

If your validations are simple, using not null constraints or check constraints might be a best option.

Comment: There's no point in a trigger... you can use not null or check constraints in the OPs situation...

Comment: You can't; but you can with a check constraint.

Comment: As @Ben said, in this question the use of a trigger for NULL checks makes no sense.  You can concoct situations where more complex checks need to be made, and done in different ways, but if we start going down that road (where we answer questions the OP hasn't asked) we'll soon have a database-in-a-database implemented, and then may Cthulhu have mercy upon us.  (Although, as Cthulhu has told me in dark visions of madness, he prefers ketchup to mercy).  Share and enjoy.

Comment: Completely agree. So, I've answered the question or not? You are reducing the accepted answer to a "don't do that, it's stupid", and not really answering it. At the same time, you are criticizing me when I try to awswer it, not making assumptions on how it came up.

Comment: I disagree with your comment @jagra. The best answers are "don't do that; here's what you should do instead and why. If you are absolutely dead set on completing what you were doing then here's how you should go about it". You haven't answered incorrectly, I just don't think you've answered well. See, I guess, Frank's answer for comparison. He clearly identified the preferable way of doing this and then pointed out what was wrong and included code to demonstrate (not that I'd code it that way).

Comment: I agree that Frank's answer is better. He only misses referring the comparison with null, but giving the correct implementation code. So, I upvoted is answer.